# Qt removing the frame?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Is there an efficient way of removing the frame and setting the background colour to transparent in Qt?  Another thing I would like to make is to have the window being "moveable" too i.g. whenever I press and and hold the left mouse button I can move the window wherever I like.

Graphically to express the result I would like to achieve.

[image]

[image]

### ----------

Solution in order to make it "moveable": https://forum.qt.io/topic/34354/solved-frameless-window-dragging-issue/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to set the window flag (i do this in an overloaded QDialog::exec):

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Dialog);
```

(just add Qt::FramelessWindowHint to your window flags)

Then you add transparent background:

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

...and make sure `autoFillBackground` is not set (uncheck in Designer if checked)

If you need to add a shadow, simply add a DropShadowEffect to the widget which creates the backgroud rounded rectangle:

```
auto dropShadow = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect;
dropShadow->setOffset(0);
dropShadow->setBlurRadius(40);
dropShadow->setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0, 180));
ui.backgroundWidget->setGraphicsEffect(dropShadow);
```

The shadow is painted on the widget itself, so you need additional space around your background widget. I.e. if your BlurRadius is set to 40 you should set a 40 pixel margin:

```
layout()->setMargin(40);
```

Comment: Wow that is fantastic! Any idea on how to make it "moveable" as I mentioned above?

Comment: I don't know if there is a simple way to make it "moveable". I would override mouseDownEvent, mouseUpEvent and mouseMoveEvent. Use mouseDownEvent to store the mouse position relative to the widget and the parent widget and in mouseMoveEvent set the widget position so that the stored widget relative position ends up under the current parent widget relative mouse position.

Comment: I think that's worthy to be a question of its own.

Comment: I figured out how to make it moveable, whoever is interested, have a look here:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/34354/solved-frameless-window-dragging-issue/2